# Dapper .net, Bulk insert, how to enforce referencial integrity, when inserting master and detail table simultaneusly

Tags: bulkinsert, dapper-plus

I am doing bulk insert into a SQL table using Dapper plus. I am facing challenge in maintaining referential integrity between master table and detail table.
Here is the code.

```
  var userName = Environment.UserName;

        DapperPlusManager.Entity<HardwareComponentType>("WithInsertIfNotExists").Table("dbo.HardwareComponents")
                                     .UseBulkOptions(options => {
                                         options.InsertIfNotExists = true;
                                     }).Identity(x=>x.ComponentId).Map("Name", "Name").Map("Status", "Status").MapValue(DateTime.Now, "ModifiedDateTime").MapValue(userName, "ModifiedByUser");

  DapperPlusManager.Entity<HardwareComponent>()
       .Table("dbo.HardwareComponentDetails").Identity(x=>x.ComponentDetailsId).Map("NodeID", "NodeID").Map("Name","Name").Map("Level", "Level").Map("Status", "Status").Map("DateSinceOperational", "DateSinceOperational").Map("IsWorkAssigned", "IsWorkAssigned");

  var hardwareComponents = hardwareComponentTypes.SelectMany(x => x.Components.Where(y => y.NodeID != null)).ToList();

  //bulk insert here  

  dbConnection.BulkInsert(hardwareComponentTypes).ThenBulkInsert(hardwareComponent=> hardwareComponent.Components );
```

here is my class structure (master object):

```
  public class HardwareComponentType
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// ComponentId.
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    public int ComponentId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Name.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Status.
    /// </summary>
    public string Status { get;set;}

    public int Order { get; set; }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Components List.
    /// </summary>
    public List<HardwareComponent> Components { get; set; }
}
```

Detail object

```
 public class HardwareComponent
 {

    /// <summary>
    /// Component DetailsId.
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    public int ComponentDetailsId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// ComponentId.
    /// </summary>
    public int ComponentId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// NodeId.
    /// </summary>
    public string NodeID { get; set; }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Level.
    /// </summary>
    public int? Level { get; set; }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Name.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Status.
    /// </summary>
    public string Status { get; set; }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Date Since Operational.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime? DateSinceOperational { get; set; }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Is Work Assigned.
    /// </summary>
    public bool? IsWorkAssigned { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, Master tables primary key (ComponentId) is foreign key in Detail table.
I want that when records are inserted in detail table, then it should get the corresponding ComponentId from Components Table.

So, should I do two separate insert statements or the current statement enough? Or else how do I achieve referential integrity:

```
dbConnection.BulkInsert(hardwareComponentTypes).ThenBulkInsert(hardwareComponent=> hardwareComponent.Components );
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want that when records are inserted in detail table, then it should get the corresponding ComponentId from Components Table.

You can either use one of the following solution in your mapping:

- [AfterAction](https://dapper-plus.net/getting-started-identity-propagation#afteraction)
- [ThenForEach](https://dapper-plus.net/getting-started-identity-propagation#thenforeach)

Such as:

```cs
DapperPlusManager.Entity<HardwareComponentType>("WithInsertIfNotExists").Table("dbo.HardwareComponents")
     .UseBulkOptions(options => {
         options.InsertIfNotExists = true;
     }).Identity(x=>x.ComponentId).Map("Name", "Name").Map("Status", "Status").MapValue(DateTime.Now, "ModifiedDateTime").MapValue(userName, "ModifiedByUser")
     .AfterAction((actionKind, master) =>
     {
         if (actionKind == DapperPlusActionKind.Insert || actionKind == DapperPlusActionKind.Merge)
         {              
             if (master.Components != null)
             {
                 master.Components.ForEach(x => x.ComponentId = master.ComponentId);
             }
         }
     });
```